# gcloud sql databases in a bash script

Tags: bash, gcloud

In the terminal (bash), when I type:

```
gcloud sql databases create $DATABASE_NAME --instance=${SQL_INSTANCE} --project $PROJECT
```

the database is successfully created.

However, when I put that same line in a bash script, I get the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud) The project property must be set to a valid project ID, not the project name ["project_name"]
To set your project, run:

  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID

or to unset it, run:

  $ gcloud config unset project
```

Even when I add `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID` to the script, I still get the same error.

How I can make the `gcloud sql databases create` work in a bash script ?

Note : I run a OS X v10.15.7 (Catalina)

Comment: Did you tried `--project=${PROJECT}`?

Comment: yes doesn't work neither

Comment: I'm wondering if it is an authentication pb...

Comment: Is it possible that `$PROJECT` variable in shell contains project ID value? Error and documentation says that `--project` param must contains ID, not name.

Comment: Are you setting $PROJECT variable inside of the bash script? If not are you exporting that variable before calling the bash script to ensure the variable is available in the bash shell?

Comment: yes $PROJECT is available in the script, I even echoed the command that I'm trying to run, copy pasted it in a terminal and it worked. But in the bash script it doesn't. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `--log-http` helped me see where the problem was.

The value of the variables `PROJECT`, `SQL_INSTANCE`, and `DATABASE_NAME` included quotes (`"`), such that the URL used to `POST` was containing `%22`.

Making the value of these variables without these quotes solved the problem.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer so other community members can use your solution.